# How to find condition of three planes intersecting at a point (according to vector approach)?

Tags: analytic-geometry

For example, if

Plane 1: $2x+y+z=1$

Plane 2: $x-y+z=2$

Plane 3 : $4x-y+3z =5$

How to check if these planes intersecting at a single point?
I want to check the coordinates of intersection , from scalar triple product or solving from normals of the planes .

Comment: See [here](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Plan3D/3PlanesIntersection_.htm).

Comment: What do you mean by "vector approach"?  Writing it in the matrix form $A(x,y,z)^T = b$ involves an unknown vector, so this can be called "vector approach"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to solve the linear systems formed by the equations of your planes, and to see whether it has solutions or not.